# Show Sum only if Sum > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to receive the MobileNr Amount for 01.05.2021.

This is my query with which I tried to group those accounts, is this the right way?

```
DECLARE @specified_date DATE;
SET @specified_date = '01.05.2021';

SELECT
    CustomerNr, MobileNr, 
    ROUND(SUM(CASE  
                  WHEN Bil_Start_Date = @specified_date 
                      THEN Price
                      ELSE 0 
              END), 2) AS Summ
FROM
    BillingTable  
WHERE
    MobileNr <> ''
GROUP BY
    CustomerNr, MobileNr
```

If I wrote everything well, how can I not show accounts `where Summ > 0`?

This is my SQL Server `BillingTable` with sample data:

| CustomerNr | Bil_Start_Date | Price | MobileNr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 337.05 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 72.69 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 0.27 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 9.6 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | -409.74 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | -0.27 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | -9.6 | 136550 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 120.51 | 137496 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 34.53 | 137496 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 59.76 | 137496 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | 0.12 | 137496 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | -120.51 | 137496 |
| 34776 | 01.05.2021 | -59.85 | 137496 |

I would like the result to be as follows:

```
CustomerNr    MobileNr    Summ
---------------------------------
   34776      137496      34.56
```

Thank you all for your suggestions and help

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Comment: And you should tag the DBMS, not the client (unless the question is explicitly about the usage of that client. A query that's just executed via that client is not.) I corrected that for you.

Comment: @stickybit I'm sorry, I already inserted a post and I couldn't format the data from the table well, I put it in the html table now

Comment: See the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) on how to create tables. I fixed that for you. The best way to present an SQL table however is by providing its `CREATE` statement and `INSERT` statements for the sample data (as text, not a  image or external link). That way anybody who wants to help you but wants to setup a test environment to work on the solution can start right away with as less friction as possible. And that, needless to say, increases the likelihood for you to get an answer (at all or faster).

Comment: @stickybit Thanks. Is this now that you have corrected my insert OK, do I need to create a table and make an insert query? since this is just one part of the current table for me, which is huge.

Comment: I guess you can leave this question as it is for now. But keep it in mind for future questions. You're not supposed to dump the whole table though. Provide a [example] that demonstrates the problem. Leave irrelevant details away for example columns that don't play a role and only keep that much rows that all cases are covered. Yes, that's a little work but you may often find the solution yourself in the process as it shifts focus on the really problematic things. And if you don't, again, a question with a proper [example] is better received increasing the likelihood of getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` statement in this case:

```
HAVING sum(.....) > 0
```

This is the statement structure:

```
   SELECT
        select_list
    FROM
        table_name
    GROUP BY
        group_list
    HAVING
        conditions;
```

The `HAVING` clause is often used with the GROUP BY clause to filter groups based on a specified list of conditions.

In this syntax, the `GROUP BY` clause summarizes the rows into groups and the `HAVING` clause applies one or more conditions to these groups.

Comment: can't find ' having Summe > 0', shows error, this example is not good

Comment: @dejanm, column aliases are created _after_ the HAVING clause is evaluated. YOu need to use the SUM() instead.

Answer (score 2):

ADJUST THIS :

```
ROUND(sum(CASE  
             WHEN Bil_Start_Date = @specified_date AND PRICE >= 0 THEN Price
              ELSE 0 )



GROUP BY 
       CustomerNr, MobileNr 
HAVING 
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Bil_Start_Date = @specified_date THEN Price ELSE 0 END), 2) > 0
```

Comment: I don't want the price to be> 0, just the Summ which is> 0 to show

Comment: use having clause after group by: in your case GROUP BY
    CustomerNr, MobileNr HAVING ROUND(SUM(CASE  
                  WHEN Bil_Start_Date = @specified_date 
                      THEN Price
                      ELSE 0 
              END), 2) > 0

Comment: @dejanm check the code above. I have adjusted

Comment: this should be a good solution, i have yet to test. thanks